# Append tag to url on response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node and express for a web app.
I'd like to add a tag to my url when someone clicked on it but on the server side:

```
exports.route = function (state) {
    return function (req, res) {
        // here I'd like to add a line of code that will turn 
        // my url from 'http://path/index' to 'http://path/index?param=myParams' 
        res.render('index', {myParams});
    };
};
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple redirect:

```
if(!req.params.param) return res.redirect(req.url+'?param='+myParams);
```

If the querystring parameter is not defined or doesnt have the value you want, just redirect the user to the same url but with the parameter.